# Is there a tool to rotate screen content without the need to physically rotate the screen?

Tags: windows-7, scaling, orientation, display-rotation

I'm working with/on a software that is optimized for screens in portrait mode and some of the features rely on this orientation, so things won't work or won't be displayed correctly with landscape orientation.

In the Windows 7 settings, I can rotate the screen content which works fine, but I'd have to physically rotate my screen to make this useful, which I unfortunately can't. Rotating my head isn't the most ergonomic solution either.

So a tool to rotate the screen content and display the result in portrait mode would be useful. Of course, there would be some scaling drawbacks involved as the vertical resolution is much smaller, but I could live with that.

Is there something like this? Of course, feel free to recommend alternative solutions.

Comment: It's really a strange question:). Forcing a monitor to display on e.g.  768X1024 instead of 1024X768 sounds weird and it's type of a setting I've never seen. Have you tried to install tools for settings custom resolution? That might help.

Comment: Forcing a custom resolution that meets his aspect ratio requirements while keeping the monitor and desktop physically upright is probably the best option. Most display drivers have built-in options for defining custom resolutions.

Comment: This would be an on-topic post at [SE Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use remote desktop to achieve this.

Have your program running in another computer or a virtual machine, then on your computer, go to start/run and type in the following command:

mstsc /w:768 /h:1024

Connect to that computer and that's what you want. You can change the resolution as you wish.

Comment: That's a nice alternative solution, thanks. Not optimal because it's not working with `localhost`, but close to what I need.

Comment: To enable a remote connection to `localhost`, these looks promising: http://www.virtualhelp.me/windows/195-remote-desktop-over-ssh-in-windows-7